# rails each method reset in controller workaround

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have this in my controller at the moment:

```
popular = Impression.select('impressionable_id, count(impressionable_id) as total').group('impressionable_id').order('total desc')
popular.each do |popevents|
  @events = Event.where(id: popevents.impressionable_id)
end
```

Basically all this is doing is selecting the most popular events that are saved in the impressions table  and getting all the event information.

So in my view i have this:

```
  <% @events.each do |e| %>
  <pre>
    <%= e.eventname %>
  </pre>
  <% end %>
```

I was expecting to see around 4-5 event names here, However i'm only seeing 1. I'm guessing its because the @events is getting reset?

What would be the work around for this?

Sam

Comment: Can you add your model code? I don't get your relations at the moment.

Comment: What does `@events.length` give you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could do something like:

```
@events = popular.flat_map do |popevents|
  Event.where(id: popevents.impressionable_id)
end
```

And it would give you the full list of events. But this is very inefficient; as it is going to run a single query for each id.

A better way would be:

```
@events = Event.where(id: popular.map(&:impressionable_id))
```

which would do it all in one query.